# Convergence of tangent lines

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, general-topology

In elementary calculus, the derivative is often motivated as the slope of the tangent line. This is often illustrated by a picture of a line through two points somehow converging to a tangent line.

My question is how to make this convergence rigorous. Is there some kind of topology on the subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which describes the convergence of lines to the tangent line, and possible other objects like Taylor polynomials, oscullating circles or tangent planes.

Of course it seems clear that we somehow want that if $f_n:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ converges to some $f$ (for some convenient notion of convergence) then $f_n^{-1}(C)$ converges to $f^{-1}(C)$ for all well-behaved $C$, and we probably want some kind of converse too.

Sorry that I cannot be more formal, but my question is whether there is some kind of theory that deals exactly with this. Is there some kind of book that covers this subject?

I already know about the Hausdorff metric, but it doesnt give us the right idea of convergence in our case, although I think it would give the right idea of convergence for compact sets such as circles converging to the oscullating circle. But even if this is the case, it seems nontrivial to show that circles converge in the Hausdorff metric iff their equations converge.

Comment: You don't need a topology on subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, just a topology on lines, and since lines are described by linear equations an obvious choice of topology is the one where convergence means the coefficients of the linear equations converge. That's enough for this application.

Comment: Sure that works, but my question is whether there is a convenient topology on the subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that includes this as a special case, as also the cases of convergence of other algebraic or analytic sets, and many other cases like iterated function systems etc etc.

Comment: You may equip the space with a bounded metric (i.e., $\arctan d(\cdot,\cdot)$ where $d$ is the usual metric), and then use Hausdorff distance. However, if you want to apply this to _all_ subsets of the space, this does not work, as sometimes the distance between two distinct sets will vanish.

Comment: A philosophical problem with this question is that the notion of derivative is local (so depends not on the whole function but on its germ). On the other hand, @mumass wants to define a nice topology on the space of graphs of functions defined on larger sets than just germs. If one accept non-Hausdorff topologies as the answer, then one can consider the topology on the set of (germs of) $C^1$-functions defined by the pseudometric $d(f,g)=|f(x_0)-g(x_0)|+|f'(x_0)-g'(x_0)|$ , where $x_0$ is a fixed point. In this pseudometric the distance from a $C^1$-function to its tangent line is just zero.

Answer (score 0):

The set of lines in the plane can be easily parametrized by a surface $M$ and the convergence can be taken in the sense of convergence in $M$.  Thus, represent the line by an equation $ax+by=c$ where $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1$ with $c$ arbitrary. This gives a unique representation of the line except for the equivalence of triples $(a,b,c)$ and $(-a,-b,-c)$. Therefore the surface in question is an "antipodal" quotient of the cylinder $S^1\times\mathbb R$.

Similar considerations apply in higher-dimensional space.